# What is correct Tomcat rewrite rule and condition to forward request to new host along with urL?

Tags: apache, tomcat, redirect, mod-rewrite, proxy

I am new with tomcat rewrite valve, looking for correct tomcat rewrite syntax to forward all request coming at `www.olddomain.com/*` to be forwarded to `www.newdomain.com/*` along with forwarding all the suffix in the request.

tomcat version apache-tomcat-8.5.82

Added below value under context in `server.xml` file but I am not sure about the syntax in rewrite.config which I created in tomcat `/conf` directory

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
```

rewrite.config:

```
RewriteRule https://www.olddomain.com/(.*) https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [H]
```

Comment: I was able to get it working after making following changes:

1.Moved rewrite.config file to application's WEB-INF folder 
```
      RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R,NE]
```
2. Added rewrite valve in tomcat conf/context.xml
```
     <Context>
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve"/>
     </Context>
```

Comment: Please add your solution as an "answer" (and later accept it), rather than post a (unformatted) "comment". Otherwise, other readers won't find it and the question is effectively "unanswered".